# Validate text box in Excel VBA

Tags: validation

I have a form that contains several text boxes.  I use the following procedure to validate that the active text box is not left blank.  If so, then the text box resets to a value of 0 and it works

Sub UFDataEntryCheckValue()

```
With UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl
    If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Or UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Input must be a number and can not be blank"
       UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl.Value = 0

    End If
End With
```

However, there is one text box that needs to be reset to a vaklue of 36 and when I add the following statement to the above procedure, I get an error

```
Dim Ctrl As Control

With UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl
    If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Or UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Input must be a number and can not be blank"
        '.Value = vbNullString
        If Ctrl.Name = "DE_Text_Term" Then
            Ctrl.Value = 36
                Else: UF_DataEntry.ActiveControl.Value = 0
        End If
    End If
End With
```